# Angular Sidebar Treeview not responding

Tags: angular, adminlte

I used Adminlte 2.4.10 template for my Angular 7. But the Treeview dropdown is not responding.

The ones with treeview are not working. I tried to inspect the page, but there is no error.

This is not working, instead it takes me back to the home page. I removed the #, but the problem is still there:

```
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars" data-toggle="dropdown"></i> <span>Academics</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a routerLink="/classes">Classes</a> </li>   
            <li><a routerLink="/classarm">Class Arm</a> </li>  
            <li><a routerLink="/department">Sessions</a> </li>  
            <li><a routerLink="/exam">Exam</a> </li>  
            <li><a routerLink="/attendance">Attendance</a> </li>  
            <li><a routerLink="/report">Report</a> </li>                                      
          </ul>
        </li>
```

This is working because it does not have treeview tag:

```
<li><a routerLink="/students"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> <span>Launch Simulator</span></a></li>
```

The main menu is just to display the name. When I click on the main menu, it suppose to collapse and display the sub-menu then I select the ones that I want.

Comment: hi...were you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On the side bar component use this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: "app-side-bar",
    templateUrl: "./side-bar.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./side-bar.component.css"],
})
export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        $('[data-widget="treeview"]').Treeview("init");
    }
}
```